# Stored procedure to loop through date range

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a query to retrieve April month data.

```
SELECT DATE(a.`senddate`) AS 'Date',SUM(a.`msglength`) AS 'total' FROM mytable a WHERE userid='248283' and senddate > '20170401000000' and senddate < '20170501000000' GROUP BY 1;
```

It is taking a lot of time due to size of the table. It is not possible to change structure nor add any indexes.

How do I write a stored procedure so that I can loop through each day. Something like...

```
SELECT DATE(a.`senddate`) AS 'Date',SUM(a.`msglength`) AS 'total' FROM mytable a WHERE userid='248283' and senddate > '20170401000000' and senddate < '20170402000000' GROUP BY 1;

SELECT DATE(a.`senddate`) AS 'Date',SUM(a.`msglength`) AS 'total' FROM mytable a WHERE userid='248283' and senddate > '20170402000000' and senddate < '20170403000000' GROUP BY 1;
```

till the last day.

Comment: surely a loop would take even longer than a set operation as you've got now? Also, why are you doing a SUM and then naming the column "Count"? They're two different calculations with different meanings. Naming the column "Count" is potentially misleading.